# Dynamically add/delete rows from GridView ASPX to CS (source);

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I want to create GridView like this in C# Class library:

[image]

**This is ASPXsource for UI:**

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcreated="Gridview1_RowCreated">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <FooterTemplate>
             <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row"
                    onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">Remove</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

**I want to format ASPX to CS (source), like this format :**

```
{
    myGrid = new SPGridView();
    myGrid.ShowFooter = true;
    myGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    myGrid.ID = "Gridview1";

    SPBoundField dest = new SPBoundField();
    dest.DataField = "Number";
    dest.HeaderText = "Number";

    TemplateField headerOne = new TemplateField();

    base.CreateChildControls();
}
```

I have no idea how to do this, please help.

Comment: https://rojalinsahoo.wordpress.com/2015/08/01/dynamic-gridview/ may you will get your answer.

Comment: I need "Create the gridview" be create programically with C# in Class library :

Comment: In this format:  myGrid = new SPGridView();
            myGrid.ShowFooter = true;
            myGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

Comment: It is unclear what your're asking. Do you want to create the same as the ASPX defines, but in your code? Do you want to have a remove column?..

Comment: Yes, I want this code for C# Class Library!

Comment: you can try this: `GridView1.AutoGenerateDeleteButton=True`  but then you need to add the hooks to handle the Delete.